# How to prevent AutoOpen feature for apps

Tags: macos, security

Several vendors provide their drivers with `AutoOpen` feature: image file contains single application SomeApp usually installs drivers or connection manager.

I've discovered how it works: Mac OS X finds
`SomeApp.app/Contents/MacOS/AutoOpen` executable and runs it. I've tried to create such application from scratch and this method works fine. This is huge security hole like autorun feature on Windows.

How to disable this feature permanently?

Comment: I do not have a single auto open? give me a example of such app so I can try it

Comment: Huawei/ZTE connect manager, for example

Comment: I have Huawei but it is not Auto starting.

Comment: Image auto opening can be disabled with `AT` commands. I can share my connection manager if you want.

Comment: sure go ahead answer your question

Comment: Link to mega: http://bit.ly/1IsMxUm